# Use Sets in composition

Tags: java

So, I have a class with a composition relationship with many instances of another class.

I used the following code:

```
public class dungeon{ 
public Set<Character> character;    

 public dungeon(){
    super();
    Set<Character> = new Set<Character>;
}
}
```

But this doesn't work. (Might be obvious, but I don't know what to do)

How would I fix this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't work because [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is an interface and you can't instantiate interfaces.

You have to use one of the classes that implement the `Set` interface, for example, `TreeSet`:

```
character = new TreeSet<Character>();
```

Or `HashSet`:

```
character = new HashSet<Character>();
```

BTW, it would be good idea to make `character` private instead of public (see [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)).

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem if I used this.character would it?

Comment: That wouldn't be a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is a syntax error:

`public dungeon(){
    super();
    character = new HashSet<Character>;
}`

HashSet, or any class that implements Set interface.

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem if I used this.character would it?

Answer (score 1):

`Set` is interface. so you can not create it with new. you need a implemented object. `HashSet` can be useful.

```
public class dungeon{ 
   public Set<Character> character;    
   public dungeon(){
      super();
      character =  new HashSet<String>();
   }
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't be a problem if I used this.character would it?

Comment: yes. there is no local character variable. so it can be also valid without this